# relations, injective functions and proof of total ordering

Tags: functions, relations, order-theory

I have recently started learning about injective functions and can understand them to a basic level.

injective functions essentially equate to `∀x,y ∈ A f(x) = f(y) → x = y`.

Assuming finite set S has the elements in a `list: s1,s2,...,sn` (where n = |S|).
Argue the list produces a topological ordering on S using `f : S → Z`
where `f(s1) = 1, f(s2) = 2`, which essentially generalises as `f(sj) = j`.

How would I argue that this is injective? Given the aforementioned rule would `f(s1)=f(j)⟹1=j⟹j-1=0⟹s1=j` be correct? Without 2 explicit variables, I'm unsure how to go about it.

---

Assuming a relation is refined R on S by `aRb` whenever `f(a) ≤ f(b)`. Is R a total ordering on R? I would need to prove that it is reflexive, anti-symmetric, transitive and follows the Trichotomy Law. (`∀x,y∈S xRy ∨ yRx ∨ x = y`). I assume to prove it is anti-symmetric I would need to prove it is first injective? Similarly to the first question, I have a general direction, but no compass, help to understand these is appreciated.

Comment: What is a topological ordering?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos.  It is a misnomer for linear order.

Comment: To show f is injective assume f(sj) = f(sk) and prove j = k.